# Android custom keyboard writes wrong characters

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

I've made a custom keyboard for my Samsung S8. The `keyboard.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard n1:keyWidth="13.999998%p" n1:keyHeight="40.0dip" n1:horizontalGap="2.6000023%p" n1:verticalGap="10.0dip"
  xmlns:n1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Row n1:keyHeight="0.100000024px" n1:rowEdgeFlags="top" />
    <Row>
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="49" n1:keyEdgeFlags="left" n1:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="50" n1:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="51" n1:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="52" n1:keyLabel="4" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="53" n1:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="54" n1:keyLabel="6" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="55" n1:keyLabel="7" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="56" n1:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="57" n1:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="48" n1:keyLabel="0" />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

(I omitted the other rows, only the first one is included in the code).

When I tap on the keyboard numbers, instead of writing "1", "2", and so on, I get the ASCII circled numbers, such as "❶", "❷" and so on.
How could that happen? The ASCII codes are correct (48, 49, and so on).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is n1? It is in place of android: . Perhaps the `n1` is responsible.

Comment: Same issue also using `android:`

Comment: Does using the default keyboard show the same ascii rounded numbers?

Comment: Of course not, only with the custom keyboard.

Comment: Nitpicking: @codes is a Unicode codepoint list, not that other character set that doesn't apply 99.99% of the time it is mentioned. Regarding n1 vs android: Purely as an XML document, the prefix does not have any semantic value; it's completely up to individual document author. Anything that processes an XML document would/should look for the namespace URI (`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`). (For humans, conventions are nice, but n1 seems to be shorthand for "the first of the namespaces that aren't given suggestive prefixes".)  It was worth a shot, though.